# Typescript not inferring type when using type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
export class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntityGenerics = BaseEntityGenerics> extends BaseObserver<T['LISTENER']> 

    public setLocked(locked: boolean = true) {
        this.fireEvent(
            { locked: true},  //error here
            'lockChanged'
        );
    }
}
```

But this code does not have the error

```js
export class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntityGenerics = BaseEntityGenerics> extends BaseObserver<BaseEntityListener> 

    public setLocked(locked: boolean = true) {
        this.fireEvent(
            { locked: true},  //NO error here
            'lockChanged'
        );
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what type TS thinks the first code block should use. Also why does the second code block work?

[Playground link with complete example with the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=155&ssc=2&pln=146&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgM2gUQIYGMAWcC+KUEIcA5ADYQAmGAzjmQNwBQLApgB6SxzAB2MdlGTZ2cAEL12aAG7tBiFgEhkwKAIDmAfgBccAEYQIFdhn6tldGBDAAFYmAyaMMYBH564ACgCUcAF4APjhzAE9WfDYuHngYMLBxOwwoDBB2ISgAMXVrAB4AFTguIX5qOh9vNShrfXCAGjgAOhaoOv4w-2DQjv8AHzgAVzL2NX52akaJQJ6wkIC4IpKFcp8Vatq+fmRhODt6lRamttmWLpDwlW094s5S1YkVZWu7J-1x+SgVd-ZP1hYAPQAKiBLDgQLgAFU3BRgPE4PFEgicK5bjBUlgYBVkMNMe5+BUIMhQgiEuxGjAUfAUfJkeINvAUpowRDlmUtJImiyARxuNA4mS4ABZDI4Gh0QpTGbheZKZQAbTsWzgAGt2GEiYtQhUCoqALpolYVKq5GD6AQ7KBwMCNI4ncLnWZwa7eMCGsoVaYvOA-T7+X3CPX6XV2PWRf4sASZURYcRSOgyeSCBwQTRQdh0Cpsh7SOQKeAIda4twefTWDT8TSRaJ83hR4Qx8QAGWA1gUwgAEuZqKY5cDQcpwVCE9QERA4NR2JpW5k6XBYW3xl9B0CecpJ+np22Tn5AhcOpZ+yohwB5DTT-gYChwACSABE4JrKeIF6VhMfVypgNQy+itP9lCPFc4DPYALyvOAW0Xd8VzXV92xOeN2Cgt8oGrGJ+S2aMxEkXMkxgFNODCd0cwTPNFELVRi3xX8KyrFgol5WIsIbHCkJQhCSIqAAldgsGgag8nLLRGm8bxfnzdpOj3OBZAgb9+iGEYxgmEJKKAocAHEEOALBinw5FUWqDNDFGaBxAwOA6ESLBgDUPSJMUAB3egUHUCYPzXRyYAAdWACgKBydMvHE-D9CQ8iCOINMMzoR05O-ACNIhbSl10-T80M+BjIqDBkFnSzrL4uz0u8uAXOxdzR1ChQ+GJOFytc-iCUGdJqF8TyVG8u9vyC9gQu88K8PzFMYszeL5OoasmMwrAKHoT1pBPAwEygT48hUJsuNwhMOKXGZ2JnBCDmUaZs0WsiDIWCL8JOyKszuI1VXVTUtoWNUNWJJs7vwrsylMGptreyCWDUlQwGIIRMQmecjqXOh9CQeVv1orQg0gggAOa8tBkxaBd0o5RKVbJp4PhmYEHwSxGOUCHgFkVx6XcyKb0EYRLwoE1030IwTDMfhGhVfQPtexpBp2xN838QniboJo4WERm9uEOgxJRf6Vf0JtfH0BLRwGXnTHMGTCcAgE4HTGBBigfgOVECgEzgHBhHEJz-OvAQccxPgYEyVx8THKybDAJ5lDsnwAEJjLgAAyGO4Aj7ymmqLRpdD5RLet-gUCvBNLGUZQogLs23PTKz2FMaHRzJmCC-D7x1Z7FW0+L5RsfgGurQWRuAboeUVTDdP687lvW87mrFFcm6pfzgui7np58F8am2FUZn8LySLtvuoIJ7NPYUjSDJhCC-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-nmFWdQLevhugOkmbWAUSJXktIKIKBYZB+A0HYGQOAAxKACBVFinFsQCXkEgFGZgtTMLPMafst5J4wDAIqJRb8XhhKVksL8gFNy+bmFhcxREcZektNSsIXSFRX6bRvAAZQKGgAAcmgbiQ0aUtMCZYE8dgCg3hPLKyVSqTm0vpfiOg4YZq8DmgtbZbz2mDMRfEYVGgsBistUKnSjrDn3AuuwZaq11q6jIE2KVMr5XcTIHqMGq8wCDAMLCPSCYYBNhBRMbwHKfyGFufzGYpDR64MkfhbwockAps-lAb+iDQ6UBBcssFEwyBPGKQxIAA)

Comment: avoid mutations in TS if you want to infer funvtion arguments. `event = {`

Comment: Try to reduce your example and make it minimum reproducible